# Unable to play deezer content from javascript-samples. VALID_TOKEN_REQUIRED

Tags: deezer

I'm exploring the capabilities of deezer javascript sdk.

All looks fine and working on the developer.deezer.com site but when I'm trying to replicate this on my localhost http server it fails to play any song.

1. create a deezer app with domain being my local ip.
2. downloaded the https://github.com/deezer/javascript-samples/tree/master/basic-custom-player
3. changed the index.html to match the app id and the url to the channel.html (again, using my server local ip)
4. served the files using node.js and a serve-static
5. launched chrome (windows, latest) and directed it to the /index.html
6. login button works
7. but when I hit the play button nothing is played. The chrome network inspector shows A LOT of requests to get the pageAlbum and all those requests fail with VALID_TOKEN_REQUIRED.

Request url (the actual api_token changes with each request and is different than the one from the login request)

> http://www.deezer.com/ajax/gw-light.php?api_version=1.0&api_token=fd120a7ce34fa1e18e4cb75237785b9a&input=3&cid=00568e39151fd6bf1

Request body

> [{"method":"deezer.pageAlbum","params":{"alb_id":"2962681","lang":"ro","header":true,"tab":12}}]:

Response

> [{"error":{"VALID_TOKEN_REQUIRED":"1"},"results":{}}]

I have also tried:
- get a free domain and try from there, same result
- use the deezer widget from local html files (file:///) and from the local server (http://). same result

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that is has something to do with cookies.

I changed the browser policy to not block third party cookies. And the deezer widget started working. Then I have only allowed third party cookies from [*.]deezer.com and it continued to work. Once I chose to block again all third party cookies, the widget stopped working.